# Site não carrega por completo

Tags: html

Carreguei um site novo no servidor, estava tudo funcionando offline, quando acesso o site ele carrega de um jeito todo diferente do que era offline, só normaliza quando começo a navegar pelo site.

O endereço do site é [www.jhwebvision.com.br](http://www.jhwebvision.com.br)

Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: O site dá-me erro na consola: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`, nesta linha: `<script src="js/preloader.js"></script>`. Já tinhas dado conta?

Comment: Bom... aqui funcionou normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente algum arquivo presente localmente no seu ambiente de testes não existe ou não está acessível no seu servidor.

Segue um print do erro exibido no console de seu site.

Arrume essa dependência, a qual, provavelmente, deve estar ocasionando o não carregamento de elementos.

[image]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Quando um site funciona em um lugar mas não o outro, é bom verificar algumas coisas:

- Todos os arquivos foram transferidos para o servidor-alvo?
- O servidor tem accesso a ler esses arquivos?
- Dados de configuração foram alteradas apropriadamente? (conexões ao banco de dados, URLs fixos, linhas no arquivos de `hosts`, etc.)
- Há algum error no lado do cliente? (como foi visto pelo Fernando medeiros)

Trabalho numa empresa onde cada equipe tem um servidor próprio, tem um onde testes de integração acontece, e por último a 'produção' - e de verdade, as dores de cabeça que passo com todas as diferenças entre cada servidor....